# Customize Flag Ajax Message on Rules Trigger

Tags: 7, ajax, rules, flags

Greetings fellow Drupalers,

We're using Rules to listen for a flag trigger. And we wanted to present a custom mesage set in rules to the user after he triggered this as well. Since we're using the AJAX toggle, no message would be presented, however since there's no page load.

What's the best course of action for the desired funcionality? Or even which direction would you follow?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules don't support siuch feature. Change "Link type" to Normal link or Confirmation form, so you will got drupal messages from Rules.